# Format a string containing Phone numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string containing phone numbers separated by `,`,

```
phone = "08763843478,+918763843478,08763843478,+918763843478,+918763843478"
```

I want to format it by removing the `0` and `+91`. Using ruby only.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have to remove the +91 and 0 which are present in the beginning of the string containing the multiple data into it.

Comment: **You** have to remove some substring. **You** also should try and show that you tried before asking others to do the job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take care of `0`'s in between the phone numbers

```
phone="08763843478,+918763843478,08763843478,+918763843478,+918763840008"
phone.split(',').map{|num| num.gsub(/^\+91|^0/, '')}.join(',')

#=> "8763843478,8763843478,8763843478,8763843478,8763840008"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
phone="08763843478,+918763843478,08763843478,+918763843478,+918763843478"

phones_list=phone.split(',')

@ph_list=[]


phones_list.each do | ph_no |
  puts "ph_no :#{ph_no}"
  if ph_no[0,1] == '0'
    ph=ph_no[1..-1]
    puts "After Removing 0 : => #{ph}"
    @ph_list.push(ph)
  elsif ph_no[0,1] == '+'
    puts "Ph Number  with + => #{ph_no}"
    ph=ph_no[3..-1]
    puts ph
    @ph_list.push(ph)
  end
end

puts "Final List : #{@ph_list}"
```

Comment: Reason for -1 ?